# How to find if a folder exists in hadoop or not?

Tags: shell, hadoop, bigdata

I need to find if the input folder location exists or not in hadoop .

I am using the following command to do the same

```
 hadoop fs -test -d <folder Location>
```

The query does not throw any error but also no output . I have checked it for both correct and incorrect location . What I understood from the documentation that it suppose to output 1 in case of correct location .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hdfs dfs -test -d <folder location>` doesn't output anything, like `0` or `1`. It's about exit status, `0` stands for a normal situation when the directory exists. `1` means a missing directory.

Here's an example you can use it in bash:

```
hdfs dfs -test -d /tmp && echo 'dir exists' || echo 'sorry, no such dir'
```

Answer (score 3):

thanks @Mikhail Golubtsov . Using the above hint my final modified shell script is

```
if hadoop fs -test -d  $1 ;
then echo "yeah it's there "
else
echo  "No its not there." 

fi
```